# Dados não estão indo para Database MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

A pagina não exibe erro nenhum, já coloquei o ini_set('display_errors', 1), porém não aparece nada de erros, ela carrega, porem ela também não redireciona para minha pagina final, fica apenas uma página em branco

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { //CSRF
    header('Location: index.php');

}

$servidor = '...';
$usuario = '...';
$senha = '...';
$banco = '...';
$conexao = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha,$banco);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Erro ao conectar: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $endereco = htmlspecialchars(($_POST['endereco']));
    $cep = htmlspecialchars(($_POST['cep']));
    $estado = htmlspecialchars(($_POST['estado']));
    $nome = htmlspecialchars(($_POST['nome']));
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO dados (email, endereco, cep, estado, nome) VALUES ('$email', '$endereco','$cep','$estado','$nome')
");
    header("Location: retorno.php");

}

?>
```

Codigo HTML:

```
<form name="Form1" class="needs-validation" novalidate action="api.php" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" name="total" id="total" value="20">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="firstName">Primeiro Nome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="" value="" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Insira um nome válido!
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="email">Email <span class="text-muted">(Opcional)</span></label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="exemplo@exemplo.com">
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Insira um email válido!
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="address">Endereço</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Rua Exemplo N1234" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Insira um endereço válido!
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row"> 
              <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <label for="zip">CEP</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" id="zip" placeholder="" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Insira um CEP Válido!
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="mb-4">

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Enviar</button>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alguns erros podem estar provocando isso:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="" value="" required>
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="exemplo@exemplo.com">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Rua Exemplo N1234" required>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" id="zip" placeholder="" required>
```

Note aqui nesse input que ele possui dois campos `ID` e não possui campo `NAME`. O `PHP` vai usar o campo `NAME` dos inputs para criar o array com os valores passados, ou seja no `PHP` os offsets de `$_POST` devem ser os mesmos colocados em `NAME` nos inputs do formulário:

```
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$endereco = htmlspecialchars(($_POST['endereco']));
$cep = htmlspecialchars(($_POST['cep']));
$estado = htmlspecialchars(($_POST['estado']));
$nome = htmlspecialchars(($_POST['nome']));
```

Perceba que aqui no exemplo retirado do seu post você usa offsets `[""]` que não existem em `NAME` nos inputs do formulário, deveria ser assim

```
$firstName = htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstName']);
$address = htmlspecialchars(($_POST['address']));
$zip = htmlspecialchars(($_POST['zip']));
$email= htmlspecialchars(($_POST['email']));
```

**Verifique nos demais campos.**

E o principal

```
#SUBMIT SEM O ATRIBUTO NAME
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">
#O PHP NUNCA VAI ACHAR O $_POST["submit"]
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {


#SUBMIT COM O ATRIBUTO NAME
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" name="submit">
#O PHP VAI ACHAR O $_POST["submit"]
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
```